# Exibir últimas 5 linhas de um arquivo com PHP?

Tags: php, arquivo

Através do `Shell`, consigo exibir as últimas 5 linhas de um arquivo através do comando `tail`.

Assim:

```
> tail -n 5 public/index.php
```

Eu gostaria de fazer a mesma coisa no PHP. Porém não queria carregar o arquivo todo, mas exibir realmente somente as últimas 5 linhas.

Sei que é possível exibir as 5 primeiras assim:

```
$f = new SplFileObject('public/index.php');

$f->rewind();

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $f->fgets();
}
```

Mas como posso fazer para exibir as últimas 5 linhas de um arquivo, mantendo uma boa performance?

**Observação**: Não quero uma solução onde tenha que abrir a linha de comando via PHP.

Comment: :D tomara que tenha um jeito facil de fazer isso.

Comment: performasse ou performance?

Comment: Eiu sempre confundo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor solução performática que consegui desenvolver foi essa:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('text.txt');
$file->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);

$linesTotal = $file->key();
$startLine = $linesTotal - 5;

for ($x = $startLine; $x <= $linesTotal; $x++) {
    $file->seek($x);
    echo $file->current().'<br>';
}
```

Alguns dados do teste:

> ```
> Tamanho do arquivo: 197 MB
> Média de tempo de execução: 2.4412620067596 seconds
> ```

Answer (score 4):

E por quê não usar o `tail`?

```
$file = escapeshellarg('tmp.txt');
$rs = `tail -n 5 $file`;
echo $rs;
```

O teste foi feito num arquivo de 2mb, 92442 linhas.

Tempo de execução: 0.107839 (1 milionésimo de segundo)

Para confirmar a integridade da performance, o mesmo arquivo foi aumentado em 8 vezes, 16mb.

O tempo de execução foi o mesmo.

```
Windows 10 Pro 64bit
PHP 5.6.9
Apache 2.4.10
```

Comment: Resposta: Porque você não consegue fazer isso em servidores compartilhados.

Comment: -1 Como foi dito na própria pergunta, eu não gostaria de soluções que utilizasse a linha de comando.

Comment: Esses tipos de comandos simples que não afetam em nada a segurança do ambiente, são geralmente liberados mesmo em servidores compartilhados. Linha de comando não é sinônimo de brecha de segurança.

Comment: mas que motivo para dar um negativo hein... rsrs

Answer (score 4):

Baseando-me na solução maravilhosa do @DaltonMenezes, desenvolvi uma classe com o método `tail`, para fazer tal operação.

Vejamos:

```
class FileObject extends SplFileObject {

    public function tail($amount)
    {
        $lastKey = $this->key();

        $this->seek(PHP_INT_MAX);

        $end = $this->key();

        $start = $end - $amount;

        // Set as last Line of iterations 

        $this->seek($lastKey);

        return new LimitIterator($this, $start, $end);
    }
}
```

O uso disso seria:

```
$f = new FileObject('text.txt');

foreach ($f->tail(5) as $key => $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Isso resulta em:

```
Essa é a linha 9995
Essa é a linha 9996
Essa é a linha 9997
Essa é a linha 9998
Essa é a linha 9999
```

Answer (score 3):

Abra o arquivo com a função `file` e use a função `array_slice` para pegar as últimas 5 linhas:

```
$linhas = file('arquivo.txt');
$linhas = array_slice($linhas, -5);

print_r(implode(PHP_EOL, $linhas));
```

Comment: +1 Achei bacana essa solução, mas será que não há alguma maneira de as outras linhas não entrarem no processamento por questão de economia de memória. Digo, imagina um arquivo de `50MB`...

Comment: A função `file` retornará todas as linhas do arquivo num `array`, não é isso?

Comment: É isso mesmo. Estou vendo uma solução mais prática.

Comment: Eu tinha pensado em usar `new LimitIterator(new SplFileObject())`. Porém como é que vou saber o "limite" já que no PHP não tem como saber qual é a última linha!?!?