# Ler as últimas 5 linhas de um arquivo através do Python

Tags: python, arquivo

Fiz essa pergunta aqui no Stackoverlow [Exibir últimas 5 linhas de um arquivo com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84002/exibir-%C3%BAltimas-5-linhas-de-um-arquivo-com-php)

Agora gostaria de saber como é que eu poderia fazer a mesma coisa em Python.

Como poderia obter as últimas 5 últimas linhas de um arquivo grande, sem ter que carregar ele totalmente para memória em Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução mais elegante que encontrei (dentre as várias que existem) é esta:

```
def tail(f, n):
    assert n >= 0
    pos, lines = n+1, []
    while len(lines) <= n:
        try:
            f.seek(-pos, 2)
        except IOError:
            f.seek(0)
            break
        finally:
            lines = list(f)
        pos *= 2
    return lines[-n:]
```

[Tirei daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280083/1314276).

Comment: este metodo é muito complicado...

Answer (score 1):

A minha sugestão inclui utilizar um iterator com `for...in`. Isso usa relativamente pouca memória e permanece bastante legível, em minha opinião.

```
def tail_file(file_name, number):
    lines = []
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line.rstrip())
            if len(lines) > number:
                lines.pop(0)
    return lines
```