# Pra que serve o assert no Python?

Tags: python, assert

O @CiganoMorrisonMendez me deu uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/84255/4995) numa pergunta anteriormente feita sobre `Python`.

E como sou iniciante no Python ainda, fiquei sem saber pra que serve o `assert` que ele indicou na resposta.

O trecho do código que ele indicou é esse:

```
assert n >= 0
```

Resta a pergunta: Como funciona o `assert` e quando devo usá-lo?

Comment: Você fez alguma pesquisa sobre isso?

Comment: Achei algumas coisas em inglês. Pelo que entendi, parece que lança uma exceção se for falsa a condição. É o que eu acho, não tenho certeza

Comment: https://pythonhelp.wordpress.com/2012/09/09/programe-defensivamente-com-assercoes/

Comment: @DaltonMenezes,  não seria importante adicionar algumas coisas na resposta? Percebi que há uma maneira de passar uma mensagem quando o `AssertionError` é chamado.

Comment: Meu "sobrenome" é com z no final. Mendez.

Comment: Complementando as respostas, você pode passar uma mensagem para a Exception usando `assert condicao, mensagem` (ex.: `assert n == 1, "O valor de n é diferente de 1")

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O assert é uma verificação em tempo de execução de uma condição qualquer. Se a condição não for verdadeira, uma exceção AssertionError acontece e o programa pára.

Isto não se usa para condições de erro "esperadas", como por exemplo uma conexão de rede que não abriu. O objetivo do assert é auxiliar na depuração, verificando a sanidade interna do programa.

A página [Using Assertions Effectively](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively) sugere usar para verificar os tipos dos parâmetros de uma função ou método. Eu não usaria para isto. O uso mais correto é para pegar aquelas condições de erro aparentemente impossíveis (mas acabam acontecendo mesmo assim).

Se o próprio algoritmo causa um erro em caso de inconsistência, não vejo porque usar o assert. No código a seguir, é crítico que foo() retorne um número entre 0 e 5, mas o próprio código garante que um número fora de faixa levanta uma exceção:

```
n = foo()
s = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"][n]
```

Por outro lado, se "n" é crítico mas ele é utilizado para uma operação matemática, que não falharia se n estiver fora da faixa, aí o assert é interessante:

```
n = foo()
assert n >= 0 and n <= 5
s = chr(ord('a') + n)
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu tinha entendido mais ou menos para que servia o `assert`, mas só não sabia em que casos poderia aplicar.

Answer (score 12):

O `assert` existe na maioria das linguagens de programação e tem sempre a mesma função, **garantir uma condição para continuar a execução do código**.

Caso a condição não seja atendida, uma exceção é disparada, e a execução é interrompida.

O exemplo que vc citou:

```
assert n >= 0
```

Irá disparar uma exceção se o n não for maior que 0.

Veja este post no [SO-en](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142453/1997073).

**ATUALIZAÇÃO: Um Exemplo, sugerido pela IDE - Android Studio, no analisador de código.**

```
public boolean Upload(String pArqOrigem, String pArqDestino, String DiretorioDestino) {
    boolean status = false;
    FileInputStream srcFileStream =  null;

    try {
        srcFileStream = new FileInputStream(pArqOrigem);

        if (MudarDiretorio(pDiretorioDestino)) {
            myLog.info( "Mudou para: "+pDiretorioDestino);
            status = mFtp.storeFile(pArqDestino, srcFileStream);
        }

        myLog.info( "Upload OK? " + status);
        return status;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        myLog.error( "Erro: Falha ao efetuar Upload. ", e);
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            assert srcFileStream != null;
            srcFileStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

A IDE segeriu o uso do `assert` no `finally`, pois é preciso ter certeza que o objeto `srcFileStream` exista antes de fechar o mesmo.

Answer (score 5):

Vou começar dizendo que não vejo ele sendo muito usado em Python. E até mesmo em outras linguagens. Deveria ser muito mais usado para tornar o código mais robusto e eventualmente manter performance.

A função básica do mecanismo é verificar se uma condição é verdadeira, nada mais.

Então por que não fazer isso com um `if` ou mesmo deixar dar uma exceção e tratar?

Bem, primeiro que deixar dar uma exceção costuma ser abusado, e em Python percebo que há cultura disso, mas é a forma que a comunidade escolheu. É lento e não é o mecanismo adequado para muitos casos. [Já respondi sobre isso em C# que é quase a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13611/101).

Sempre que você pode evitar que o erro aconteça é melhor fazer isso antes do erro acontecer. Python não ajuda muito e incentiva o erro acontecer em muitas situações, o que não é ruim quando está usando apenas para *scripts*. E claro, há casos que é melhor deixar o erro acontecer, casos típicos de [condição de corrida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/101). Mas de forma geral exceção só deveria ser usada para tratar erros que só podem ser detetados no momento que executa algo.

Erros de programação não deveriam ser tratados nem mesmo com `if`. É aqui onde o `assert` entra. Ele existe justamente para verificar se o código fez tudo o que deveria fazer, ele não pode ser usado para verificar condições de execução.

Vou citar um erro comum que as pessoas cometem usando `if`, ou pior, exceção, onde o `assert` é adequado. Veja a [resposta que ninguém achou problemática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/316686/101). A exceção foi usada como mecanismo para verificar se o programador cometeu um erro. Um `if` seria melhor porque é possível verificar antes do erro acontecer. Porém a verificação seria feita para algo que é um **erro de programação**, é uma chamada à função equivocada, não é algo que ocorre por questão do dado entrado ou situação do ambiente. Ali tem um erro que nunca deveria existir em um código bem-feito. Ali é o caso típico de uso do `assert`.

Então o `assert` existe para tratar erros de programação. Ele deve dar indicação quando o programador, e não o usuário, fez algo errado. Ele só deve ser executado enquanto está testando a aplicação. Quando já se sabe que o código está ok ele deve ser desabilitado. E de fato, além da semântica mais específica, a grande vantagem dele é poder desabilitar em execução normal, o que permite uma performance melhor. Este é um código que só existe para testar se o código está correto e não para tratar erros normais de execução.

A resposta do Celso Marigo Jr dá um exemplo interessante porque o `assert` ali verifica se o objeto é nulo, e ele ser nulo não é um erro de execução é um erro de programação. O exemplo não é dos melhores porque ali é possível verificar por outros meios. Quase sempre o `assert` é usado apenas para testar dados que venham de fonte externa (parâmetros, mesmo que seja o `self`). Faz pouco sentido o uso no algoritmo da rotina, e se fizer um pouco é porque o código está grande demais. Claro que sempre pode existir uma situação que seja adequada.

[Veja como desabilitar a asserção](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1273211/221800). é Possível, mas não recomendo fazer um *build* do Python que não remove-as.

Então a asserção é um mecanismo para detetar erros o mais cedo possível. Ele é quase um complemento ao compilador. Ele é fundamental em códigos bem testados. E de fato códigos de [Teste de Unidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/567879/101) usam muito ele (podem usar um mecanismo mais sofisticado de um [*framework* específico](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) que substitui o `assert` padrão).

O aspecto secundário dele é documentar condição do código que deve sempre ser respeitado, de forma melhor que um comentário.

Então em vez e fazer

```
if not condicao:
    raise AssertionError()
```

você usa algo mais semântico que que pode ser mais performático.

O problema é que o uso dele para dar mais robustez ao programa é complicado de fazer em linguagem de tipagem dinâmica. Primeiro porque o compilador não trata isso, deixando o problema com o programador, e segundo porque a tipagem é mais complicada, ao contrário da crença popular. O que não é um problema para *scripts* que talvez nem precisam tanto assim do `assert`. O problema é quando a pessoa começa usar a linguagem para tarefas que ela não é adequada.

Então deixar só o erro acontecer ou tratar com exceção acaba sendo a opção mais fácil, e errada, que as pessoas adotam.

Eu queria dar um exemplo correto de uso, mas além dele ser complicado não trata outros tipos numéricos:

```
def div(a, b):
    assert isinstance(a, (int, float, complex)) and not isinstance(a, bool), "parâmetro a não é um valor numérico"
    assert isinstance(b, (int, float, complex)) and not isinstance(b, bool), "parâmetro b não é um valor numérico"
    assert b == 0, "parâmetro b não pode ser 0"
    return a / b
```

Note que outros tipos numéricos não foram aceitos, por exemplo o [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) ou outro de alguma biblioteca.

Ao contrário da crença popular, para fazer código robusto em linguagens de *script* dá muito mais trabalho, por isso é um engano achar que a linguagem é mais produtiva. Ela é para códigos muito simples que não precisem tanto assim de robustez.

Ao contrário do que diz a resposta aceita, o `assert` é interessante sempre que deseja indicar uma condição que deve sempre ser verdadeira. É claro que deixar a exceção ocorrer não trará maiores problemas, e para *script* é ok, mas para um código mais robusto é melhor documentar melhor o que está ocorrendo em vez de deixar estourar um erro colateral.

[image: Fiat 147 todo detonado andando pelas ruas]

Ali um `assert` não faz sentido porque você não sabe o que vem, pode ser que `foo()` pegue os dados externamente e portanto você não tem controle sobre o valor, não é um erro de programação, a não ser que haja uma documentação dizendo que o retorno será de uma certa forma. Mas se tem essa documentação, quem deve dar a garantia é a função e não o seu código. Se não há a garantia, então não é erro de programação e nunca pode ser desligado, por isso um `if` é mais adequado.

Se é para verificar os tipos dos dados que chegam pelos parâmetros **em todos os casos**, segundo recomendação da comunidade, então Python não é linguagem adequada. Uma linguagem de tipagem estática, de preferência com inferência, funciona melhor.

Originalmente o `assert` existe para testar valores adequados. No exemplo acima apenas ver se veio 0 seria o adequado, em uma linguagem de tipagem estática.

E vir 0 é um erro de programação, não é um dado eventual na execução. O correto é o código chamador já garantir que ele não é 0 e decidir o que fazer se for, já que a divisão não pode ser realizada.

A ideia que ele deve ser usado em condições impossíveis faz com que o programador não queira usar, já que é impossível. Mas é o possível, é o erro de programação.

[Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-python-grammar-assert_stmt).

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184957/101).

Answer (score 0):

Apenas para complementar a resposta dos outros. A [referência oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) do Python sugere que o `assert` seja usado para fins de depuração. Perceba que o fragmento

```
assert condition
```

é um completo equivalente ao trecho

```
if __debug__:
    if not condition:
        raise AssertionError
```

onde `__debug__` é uma flag *read only* determinada pelo contexto de execução. *Atualmente*, esta flag é verdadeira por padrão, mas é desativada quando for solicitada uma execução otimizada.

Essa "execução otimizada" acontece ao passar o argumento `-O` (`python3 -O main.py`) ou quando estiver estabelecida a variável de ambiente `PYTHONOPTIMIZE`. Quando esse modo otimizado estiver valendo, a flag `__debug__` será falsa e nenhum `assert` vai sequer ser executado.

Por causa disso, eu pessoalmente considero inadequado implementar lógica baseada em `assertion`s. Pelo meu entendimento, a referência oficial sugere que essas expressões de asserção sejam meramente usadas como um *sanity-check* do seu código e que não sejam imprescindíveis ao rodá-lo em definitivo (claro, isso se você der alguma importância à referência oficial).

Na versão atual do Python (3.11 no momento em que escrevo), se você não tiver o objetivo de executar código otimizado, pode usar o `assert` da maneira que os colegas sugeriram. Contudo, tenha em mente que isso pode mudar em alguma versão adiante.

Particularmente, eu uso `raise ValueError` para validar argumentos entrando numa função e "`if`s normais" para validar entrada do usuário. Importante lembrar que existe uma diferença entre `assert` e `AssertionError`: o segundo funciona normalmente quando você o invoca, independentemente da flag de depuração.