# Python, diferença entre assert e raise?

Tags: python, exceção, assert

Me deparei com uma dúvida com as estruturas `raise` e `assert` em python.

No código abaixo mostra a implementação das estruturas forçando um erro caso o número passado seja negativo.

```
def is_neg_assert(int):
    assert (int >= 0), "Número negativo"
```

---

```
def is_neg_raise(int):
    if int < 0:
        raise "Número negativo"
```

Ambas forçarão o erro caso o valor passado seja menor que **0**.

> Qual a diferença de uso e implementação entre ***assert*** e ***raise***

Comment: +1 é o tipo de pergunta que eu gosto nesse site

Comment: Eu acho que essa pergunta se auto-responde, já que tem os exemplos de código

Comment: @jsbueno eu acho que não auto-responde não. Não parece tão óbvio quando você usa uma exception com um `if`

Comment: @jsbueno, o intuito da pergunta, está voltado para saber o por que existe ambas as estruturas de "erro", e qual a forma de implementação para elas. Levando em consideração a resposta, pode-se dizer que não é o correto usar o `raise` em uma condição, essa estrutura estaria voltada mais para se usar na declaração de métodos abstratos nas classes (Pelo que eu entendi).

Comment: Se vocẽ enetendeu isso, a resposta não está boa - raise causa um erro deliberado e tem centenas de caso de uso no dia a dia - muito longe de só indicar métodos abstratos. Mas a "diferença" entre assert e raise está nos trechos de código da pergunta. Talvez a pergunta não esteja bem escrita então.

Comment: Relacionado: [Pra que serve o assert no Python?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85323/pra-que-serve-o-assert-no-python)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`raise` tem como finalidade invocar uma `Exception` no momento oportuno. Da mesma forma que as outras linguagens quando usamos o `throw new Exception`, a exceção é invocado no momento que chamarmos `raise`.

Exemplo:

```
 raise Exception('Invoquei')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: Invoquei
```

o `assert` por sua vez faz uma afirmação e, caso falhe (ou seja, retorna `False`), invoca uma Exception.

Essa afirmação ocorre a seguinte forma: Se for verdadeiro, a próxima linha continua a ser executada normalmente. Se for Falso, a exceção é lançada, com a mensagem que você passou como crítica à falha de afirmação.

Exemplo:

```
a = 1 + 1

assert a == 2, 'Conta está errada'

assert a == 3, 'Conta está errada' #Exceção é lançada aqui, pois é falso

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: Conta errada
```

Creio que no seu caso, por se tratar de um exemplo simples, a lógica usada para a crítica do argumento passado para a função,  não faz diferença. As duas são apropriadas.

Ao meu ver a diferença mais impactante entre as duas é o fato de que o `assert` sempre vai precisar de uma condição retornando `False` para invocar uma exceção. O `raise` por sua vez, é o mecanismo responsável exatamente pelo chamamento de uma exceção, independente da condição.

Um exemplo de que estou falando que o `raise` não precisa de condição é o seguinte: Imagine uma classe que você criou para ser sempre derivada e ter um determinado método sobrescrito. Se ele não for sobrescrito, preciso de lançar uma exceção avisando que é necessário sobrescrevê-lo. Eu não usaria assert, e sim raise.

Veja:

```
  class abstrata(object):

       def metodo(self):
            raise "Esse método precisa ser implementado na classe filha"


 class concreta(abstrata):

      def metodo(self):

          return "implementei com sucesso"
```

Perceba que nesse cenário `raise` tem a sua finalidade completamente diferente do `assert`, visto que eu simplesmente quero informar um erro independente de condições

Comment: +1 Gostei particularmente do último exemplo. Mas `concreta` não deveria herdar de `abstrata` - em vez de `object`?

Comment: É verdade @mgibsonbr, pelo horário que respondi dá para entender o vacilo, né? Obrigado por avisar

Comment: @mgibsonbr que bom que gostou do exemplo. Eu ainda nem programo em Python e soube explicar. Isso significa que, estudando Python, estou progredindo para um nível diferente de PHP, kkkk